# How to change local network info (ip, netmask, broadcast) using ifconfig

Tags: linux, networking, ifconfig

I am following along with the book `Linux Basics for Hackers (No Starch Press, 2018)` using Kali Linux (2019.1a) with VirtualBox and when changing my network info (chapter 3) I am no longer able to access the internet.

Here is what I did:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe77:94b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:77:09:4b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 15771  bytes 18253966 (17.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4016  bytes 243513 (237.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 20  bytes 1116 (1.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20  bytes 1116 (1.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

$ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.25.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from syd15s03-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.25.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=23.10 ms
64 bytes from syd15s03-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.25.142): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=23.4 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 23.351/23.655/23.959/0.304 ms
$ # Change IP from 10.0.2.15 to 10.0.2.21
$ ifconfig eth0 10.0.2.21 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.0.2.255
$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.21  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe77:94b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:77:09:4b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 230432  bytes 263807948 (251.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 58741  bytes 3535449 (3.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 20  bytes 1116 (1.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20  bytes 1116 (1.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

I have double checked the commands from the book, and everything I did seems to match.

How can I change my network info and not kill my network/internet access?

Answer (score 0):

**Don't try this in a remote session!!!**

When changing the ip address of eth0, which is also the interface
for your `default route`, you will have to change that too.

**Something like this:**

```
# ifconfig eth0 down
# route del default
# ifconfig eth0 10.0.2.21 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.0.2.255
# route add default eth0
```

*This is from memory, so you might want to consult the manpages*